# Probability of tossing an even number of heads is $\frac{1}{2}$ for any  (fair coin)

Tags: probability

I can't wrap my mind around this fairly simple question.

Assume that the sample case is:
$$
\Omega=\left\{ 0,1\right\} ^{n}
$$

So that $\left|\Omega\right|=2^{n}$.

I'd like to calculate the probability for this event:
$$
A=\left\{ \left(a_{1},\ldots,a_{n}\right)\in\Omega:\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}\,mod\,2\,=0\right\} 
$$

I can say intuitively that $P\left(A\right)=\frac{1}{2}$, but I'm not sure why.
I guess it works out when $\left|A\right|=2^{n-1}$ and than:
$$
P\left(A\right)=\frac{\left|A\right|}{\left|\Omega\right|}=\frac{2^{n-1}}{2^{n}}
$$
but I can't tell why $\left|A\right|$ would be equal to $2^{n-1}$.

I will be happy to get some explanation and\or intuition for this.

Comment: Fix $a_1,\ldots,a_{n-1}$, then there is precisely one choice for $a_n$ which results in $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)\in A$. Therefore, $|A|$ is the number of possible tuples $(a_1,\ldots,a_{n-1})$, which is $2^{n-1}$

Comment: Are you assuming the coin is fair (same probability for heads and tails)?

Comment: Hint: The cases of $\sum a_i=k$ is $\binom nk$.

Comment: @Taladris Yes, I have edited the question

Comment: Apart from @Mastrem's comment and Arthur's similar deleted answer, it is an easy induction: clearly true when $n=1$ and if true for $n=k$ with $|A_k|=|A_k^c| =2^{k-1}$ then $|A_{k+1}|=1\times |A_k|+1\times |A_k^c| = 2\times |A_k| =2^k$

Comment: The probability is $\frac12$ if $n\gt0$; the probability is $1$ if $n=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition is right, here's a silly way to see why: consider the map $f : \Omega \to \Omega$ which sends $(a_1, \ldots, a_{n - 1}, a_n)$ to $\left(a_1, \ldots, a_{n - 1}, \left(1 + a_n\right) \text{ mod } 2\right)$. If $\Phi(a_1, \ldots, a_n)$ is shorthand for $\left(\sum_{i = 1} a_i\right) \text{ mod } 2$ then of course we have that exactly one of $\Phi(a_1, \ldots, a_n)$ and $\Phi(f(a_1, \ldots, a_n))$ is $0$, and the other is $1$. Also observe that $f(f(a_1, \ldots, a_n)) = (a_1, \ldots, a_n)$, so that $f$ is a bijection $\Omega \to \Omega$. In particular it follows that $f$ puts $A$ into bijection with $\Omega \setminus A$. Thus $\lvert A \rvert = \lvert \Omega \setminus A \rvert$ and the only possibility is then that $\lvert A \rvert = 2^n / 2 = 2^{n - 1}$.